# getting data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, grails

I'm using Grails without the usual H2 db. Instead, I've installed MySQL locally and on my server.

I need to run queries in this MySQL database and display the data in a GSP (to be precise: I want to visualize them with highcharts). The tables, that store the required information, are not associated with the domains within my Grails project.

How can I access the data without using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

One of the wonderful things about Grails is that it's built on Spring and Groovy and all the wonderful things that they provide. Which means, you can access your datasource using the Groovy SQL package.

A very detailed Grails example can be found in this [blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-groovy-sql.html).

Here is a quick example (only slightly modified from the above blog):

```
package example

import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

class PersonService {

    // Reference to default datasource, autowired into the service through DI.
    def dataSource

    List<GroovyRowResult> allPersons(final String searchQuery) {
        final String searchString = "%${searchQuery.toUpperCase()}%"

        final String query = '''\
            select id, name, email 
            from person 
            where upper(email collate UNICODE_CI_AI) like :search
        '''

        // Create new Groovy SQL instance with injected DataSource.
        final Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)

        final results = sql.rows(query, search: searchString)
        return results
    }
}
```

It's worth looking through the Groovy API regarding [Sql class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) too.

Comment: ok, thanks, I look into that.
but I need to create a new domain and a controller for it?

Comment: You will need a controller or service to put your code into, but neither requires a domain class to work/exist. The above code has no relationship to any domain class whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

In DataSource.groovy you can configure DB for each enviroments.
By default, for dev evn H2 base used, but for production MYSQL used. 
Example of configuration:

```
development {
  dataSource {
     dbCreate = "none"  // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
     username = "root"
     password = "root"
     url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
     driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect'
//      logSql = true
  }
}
```

Using gorm http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCRUD